# Creacion de tabla dinamica

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando una tabla con js

```
for (j = 0; j < usersConCaptura.length; j++) {
            html += "<tr>";
            let contador = 0;
            html += "<td id=usersConCaptura[j].ID_U>" + usersConCaptura[j].ID_U + "</td>";
```

necesito poner como `id` el valor de `usersConCaptura[j]` pero no lo pone, como lo soluciono?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por la información que das, asumo que tu problema es que no estas concatenando el id, sino que estas poniendo el nombre de tu variable como string.

Para solucionarlo, deberías concatenar, al igual que lo haces para el contenido dentro del `<td>`

Por ende, quedaría algo así

```
for (j = 0; j < usersConCaptura.length; j++) {
    html += '<tr>';
    let contador = 0;
    html += '<td id="' + usersConCaptura[j].ID_U + '">' + usersConCaptura[j].ID_U + '</td>';
```

Saludos